# Can a custom code function return two values?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have the code below in my reports:

```vb
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()

Public Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
    suma = 0
    ct = 0

    For Each item As Object In items
        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
        ct += 1
    Next

    If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function

Public Function GetMyVal() as Decimal
    GetMyVal = suma 
End Function
```

The above function returns `suma`, and I call the function by:

```vb
code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Claim_Currency.Value,Fields!Claim_Currency.Value,Fields!Total_Paid_Loss___LAE.Value, "dataSet"))
```

I want to use both variables `suma` and `ct` in my report.

How can I adjust the function to make it return both variables and how do I then call them from the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare ct as a Public variable then you can access it in your code as Code.Variable.

```
Public ct As Integer

tb1=code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Claim_Currency.Value,Fields!Claim_Currency.Value,Fields!Total_Paid_Loss___LAE.Value, "dataSet"))

tb2=code.ct
```